# Rearrange partitions' order after cloning with Acronis True Image for Crucial

Tags: partitioning, ssd, clone

I have cloned a 1TB HDD into a 500GB Crucial MX500 SDD using Acronis True Image for Crucial software.

Originally, this was the partition order in the HDD:

[image]

But this is the partition order in the cloned SDD:

[image]

Now, the fourth partition is the first one.

Because of that, I have modified BIOS configuration to avoid the message: "Cannot find script file X:\onekey\main\irscall.vbs".

I followed the instructions from this post: [Lenovo Partition system destroyed!](https://www.eightforums.com/threads/lenovo-partition-sytem-destroyed.37584/) But now, when I power off the PC, it switches on automatically after some minutes.

I have thought to connect the new SDD to another computer and rearrange the partitions using Linux but I don't know if there is another better way, faster or saver way, to do rearrange the partitions.

How can I rearrange the partitions' order? I haven't found this option in the EASEUS Partition Master Trial Edition.

Or maybe, there is an option in the BIOS to avoid these random automatic switches on.

Comment: This cannot be done with Acronis, sadly, you will have to use a third-party partition software (of your choice) to accomplish this task.  The software you have does not have the required feature (plus it restores an image of the disk it's not a partition manager).

Comment: @Ramhound Thanks, but it is strange that changes the partitions' order.

Comment: I don't know what the Acronis image looked like.  It's not clear the reason the partition order is causing a problem with your system drive letters, you can assign any volume, any drive letter you want.  Furthermore, the partition in question, shouldn't even have a drive letter.

Comment: @Ramhound Maybe I'm wrong and I don't have to do anything with the partitions and the problem is with Lenovo OneKey rescue system. Thanks a lot!

Comment: `X:\onekey\main\irscall.vbs` So this is a custom script by Lenovo.  You would have to mount the other partitions, on your system (I don't suggest this), in order to find it.  I don't have a recent Lenovo device so I don't know how the key words works in today's devices.

Comment: @Ramhound That script is on the LBR_ESP partition. And my Lenovo device is a Lenovo Horizon 27 Table PC (ideacentre) - Type 6266 (I think from 2013).

Comment: That is extremely odd they are mounting and giving the EFI partition (ESP is often used also) a drive letter.  You can give your EFI partition a drive letter yourself I suppose.